# ios Horizontal UISlider cause UIPageViewController to slide page when not intended

Tags: ios, iphone, uislider, uipageviewcontroller

A single or multiple horizontal Sliders on a pageview cause trouble.  The user has difficulty sliding the thumb of the slider without causing the page view to slide.

Workarounds I've tried

1. overriding Pan Gesture to make minimum velocity relevant
2. putting an invisible rectangle over the sliders to capture the pan gesture
3. overriding HitTest to make the thumb tap rectangle bigger

Answer (score 5):

Best result so far was overriding Pan Gesture in custom extended UISlider class.  What happens is the Pan Gesture is detected anywhere in the UISlider rectangle rather than just the thumb.  Rock solid now, no pageview swiping.

Notes: both initWithFrame and initWithCoder are provided so sictSlider2 can be instantiated through code or through XIB.

Tap is also handled in case user taps inside slider rectangle.
Pan also has

```
[self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

because  ValueChanged events only happen when thumb is moved and thumb stops moving after a little distance when Pan handler takes over.

Happy CutAndPaste!

code:

```
#import "sictSlider2.h"

@implementation sictSlider2

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {


        UIPanGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
        recognizer.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

        UITapGestureRecognizer * recognizer2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        recognizer2.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer2];

        UIPinchGestureRecognizer * recognizer3 = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
        recognizer3.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer3];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer * recognizer4 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
        recognizer4.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer4];

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];   
    }
    return self;
}


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        UIPanGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
        recognizer.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

        UITapGestureRecognizer * recognizer2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        recognizer2.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer2];

        UIPinchGestureRecognizer * recognizer3 = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
        recognizer3.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer3];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer * recognizer4 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
        recognizer4.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer4];

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];     
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    CGPoint p = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];    
    NSLog (@"in slider tap %f %f ", p.x, p.y);

    float val = self.value;  // current slider value
    // t.x is in coords of the slider rect, so divide by width to get delta

    val = p.x/self.frame.size.width;
    [self setValue:val];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint t = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
    NSLog(@"in slider pan %f %f", t.x, t.y);

    float val = self.value;  // current slider value
    // t.x is in coords of the slider rect, so divide by width to get delta

    val = val + t.x/self.frame.size.width;

    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self setValue:val];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:recognizer.view];   
}

- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
      NSLog(@"slider SWIPE");}
@end
```

and   .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface sictSlider2 : UISlider
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
@end
```

Comment: worked great for me. Btw, you can remove the swipe and pinch recognizers and you don't need to set the delegate if you don't implement any of the methods.